# $f\in C^1$ piecewise: why should the derivative be finite on the borders of the pieces?

Tags: real-analysis, piecewise-continuity

$f\in C^1([a,b];\Bbb R)$ piecewise $\iff\ \exists\sigma= \{a=a_0<a_1<\dots<a_n=b\}$ a partition of $[a,b]\text{ such that }  f'|_{(a_i,a_{i+1})}\in C^0$ $\forall i\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ and $f\in C^0$

The function $x\mapsto\sqrt{|x|}$ is not $C^1([-1,1];\Bbb R)$ piecewise because the derivative approaches infinity at zero. But $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}|_{(0,1)}$ is continuous. The only problem is that it is not extendable by continuity to $[0,1)$.

Is that part of the definition of $f'|_{(a_i,a_{i+1})}\in C^0$ i.e. does $f'|_{(a_i,a_{i+1})}\in C^0$ imply that $f'|_{(a_i,a_{i+1})}$ should have a finite limit in $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$?

Comment: No it doesn't. take $\ln(x)$ on $(0,1]$ or $\tan(x)$ for $x\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$

Comment: According to wikipedia and my professor those aren't piecewise continuous on $[0,1]$ and $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ respectively

Comment: Usually the definition of "piecewise $C^1$" includes the condition that $f'$ have one-sided limits at the endpoinnts of the subintervals.